# Get result of two tables

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I got two tables "links" and "categories" how do i get 4 colunms from links and one from categories?

```
**Links**
_id
link_title
link_desc
link_date

**Categories**
_id
cat_title
cat_desc
```

i need a single row like this
**_id, link_title, link_desc, link_date, cat_title**

and then use this in my cursor

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor linkCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllLinks();
    startManagingCursor(linksCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{ DbAdapter.LINK_TITLE, DbAdapter.LINK_DESC, DbAdapter.LINK_DATE, DbAdapter.LINK_ROWID, DbAdapter.CAT_DESC };
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.title, R.id.content, R.id.date, R.id.headid, R.id.catdesc  };

    SimpleCursorAdapter links = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.linkrow, linkCursor, from, to);
    //links.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
    setListAdapter(links);
}
```

I tried SQL UNION but it dont worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a join. But to  do this you need to either give two ids, or add a category_id column to the Links-table.

```
SELECT
    l._id,
    link_title, 
    link_desc,
    link_date, 
    cat_title
FROM Links l,  Categories c
WHERE l._id = ?
AND c._id = ?
```

or after adding the column

```
SELECT
    l._id,
    link_title, 
    link_desc,
    link_date, 
    cat_title
FROM Links l
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON c._id = l.link_cat_id
WHERE l._id = ?
```

### More information:

- [w3schools.com/sql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) - Tutorial about SQL. Generic SQL which works for most database engines.
- [sqlite.com/lang.html](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) - Syntax reference for SQLite, which is used in Android.

Comment: return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT l._id, link_title, link_contentshort, link_date, category_title FROM links l LEFT JOIN categories c ON c._id WHERE l._id = c._id", null); the query look corret by i get an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'category_title' does not exist

Comment: I misspelled the name. I updated the answer with the correct spelling. About your query; Are you sure you want `l._id = c._id`? This will pair up links and categories with the same value of `_id`. Normally, you create a new column to hold the other key.

Comment: Thanks!!! `public Cursor fetchData() { return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT l._id, link_title, link_desc, link_date, category_itle FROM links l LEFT JOIN categories c ON l._catid = c._id ORDER BY l._id DESC", null); }` worked for me. **For what can i use WHERE? Or AND like in your first example**